# How to jump directly to a column number in Vim for short lines?

Tags: vim

I'm editing a file in Vim. It's a text file with a lot of short lines.

I want to be able to insert a character at the 15th column of each line. Some lines are longer than 15 characters, some shorter.

I tried using the "|" operator to jump to column 15, (e.g. 15| ) but it doesn't work for the short lines.

How can I do this without manually spacing out each line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set ve=all
```

then do your `15|` and add text

set ve back if necessary.

for more information about `ve` option: `:h 've'`